# SQL LOAD DATA local file

Tags: php, mysql

My data look like this.

```
company_name,brand_name,product_name,usage_annotation,organic_standard
ASB Greenworld Ltd.,ASB Greenworld Ltd.,Organic Garden Manure,,"COS,NOP"
ASB Greenworld Ltd.,ASB Greenworld Ltd.,Organic Seed & Herb Soil,,"COS,NOP"
ASB Greenworld Ltd.,ASB Greenworld Ltd.,Organic Moisture Soil,,"COS,NOP"
```

My query look like this in php

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file_url_with_name."' INTO TABLE ".$table_name." FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\'";
$sql .= " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (company_name,brand_name,product_name,usage_annotation,organic_standard);";
```

where $file_url_with_name is my file path with actual filename with extension
$table_name is table im trying to load data to.

It gives me this error:

```
WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' IGNORE 1 LINES (company_name,brand_name,product_name,usage_annotation,organic_' at line 2]
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/data/test-data.csv' INTO TABLE wpiy_test_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' IGNORE 1 LINES (company_name,brand_name,product_name,usage_annotation,organic_standard);
```

IF anyone can help that be great

Comment: `\n` must be places into $sql literally! twice the slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error that you are showing, one can see that the line terminator was not properly passed to the query.

You want: `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`, but the error log is showing: `LINES TERMINATED BY ' '`.

You just need to escape the carriage return when building the query string so it is not interpolated in PHP.

Also, as pointed out by Barmar, you need to escape the `ESCAPED BY '\\'` part so the two backslahes are passed to the query (as of now, there is just one backslash in the final query string, which also is a syntax error).

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file_url_with_name."' INTO TABLE ".$table_name." FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\\\'";
$sql .= " LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (company_name,brand_name,product_name,usage_annotation,organic_standard);";
```

Comment: This is correct, but the first error is happening earlier with `ESCAPED BY '\\'`. That also needs to be doubled.

Comment: @Barmar: ah yes, I did not notice that at first... fixed, thank you.

Comment: @GMB Server-side SQL is the most preferred :-).

Comment: Does this query has any speed issue. at this point i dont know how many rows there will be in csv file, and i will run this using cronjob daily

Answer (score 1):

From another angle this seems like simple csv file only so

```
$file = fopen($file_url_with_name, "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    $sql = "INSERT into $table_name (company_name, brand_name, product_name, usage_annotation, organic_standard) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]')";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
fclose($file);
```